# Why does it mean that $n$-th variable is removable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I'm reading the proof for "the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials" and I have a trouble with it (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)

Let $P(X_1,...,X_n)$ be a symmetric *homogeneous* polynomials in variables $X_1,...,X_n$.

Then, $P(X_1,...,X_n)$ can be decomposed as a sum of symmetric homogeneous polynomials, that is, $P(X_1,...,X_n)=P_{\text{lacunary}}(X_1,...,X_n)+ X_1...X_nQ(X_1,...,X_n)$, where lacunary part is defined as the sum of all monomials in $P$ which contain only a proper subset of variables $X_1,...,X_n$.

Then, it's written in wikipedia that "since the lacunary part is symmetric, $P_{\text{lacunary}}$ is determined by $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$."

How?

Let $\Phi$ be the endomorphism on $A[X_1,...,X_n]$ such that $\Phi$ fixes $X_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$ and $\Phi(X_n)=0$.

Then, $P(X_1,...,X_{n-1},0)=\Phi(P(X_1,...,X_n))=\Phi(P_{\text{lacunary}}(X_1,...,X_n))+ \Phi(X_1...X_nQ(X_1,...,X_n))= \Phi(P_{\text{lacunary}}(X_1,...,X_n))$

However, I don't get how $\Phi(P_{\text{lacunary}}(X_1,...,X_n))$ is equal to $P_{\text{lacunary}}(X_1,...,X_n)$. How do I assert it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Noone said that $\Phi\left(P_{\operatorname{lacunary}}\left(X_1, ..., X_n\right)\right) = P_{\operatorname{lacunary}}\left(X_1, ..., X_n\right)$. The chain of equalities that you have written does not need this.

Comment: @darijgrinberg then what does it mean written in wikipedia? Why is lacunary term is determined by just $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$?

Comment: Which part of it is unclear? The "determined by $X_1, ..., X_{n-1}$" is not what Wikipedia is saying.

Comment: @darijgrinberg "Because P is symmetric, the lacunary part is determined by its terms containing only the variables X1, ..., Xn−1, i.e., which do not contain Xn" I don't get this part.. How do I know there exists a single permitation which makes each term of lacunary part has no $X_n$?

Comment: It means that the coefficient of every which appears in the lacunary part of $P$ is equal to the coefficient of a term which appears in the lacunary part of $P$ and does not contain $X_n$ (because the lacunary part of $P$ is symmetric, and you can always permute the variables in such a way that the "lacuna" covers $X_n$). Thus, if two different polynomials $P$ have equal coefficients in front of terms which contain only the variables $X_1, ..., X_{n-1}$, then they have equal lacunary parts.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I will write what I understand now as an answer and could you check whether I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thought I understood but while writing I noticed that I didn't..

Comment: I have added some more details in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Proof_sketch . Does the argument make more sense to you now? Alas, your answer below does not strike me as very logical.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Get it now. Thank you. I didn't know why we are considering only $P(X_1,...,X_{n-1},0)$, but now I know that eventually showing that $P(X_1,...,X_{n-1},0)$ equals to some $R(X_1,...,X_{n-1},0)$ imply that they have the same lacunary. By the way which part of my argument is not logical? Last sentence starting with "apply the analogous..."?

Comment: Now that you've edited it, it makes a lot more sense! (Though there are $\cdots$'s missing on the LHS of the long equation.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Edited :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's decompose $P$ into distinct monomials, say, $P=a_1+ ... + a_k + b_1 + ... + b_l$ where $a_1+ ... + a_k$ is the lacunary part of $P$.

Let $\Phi_\sigma$ be the automorphism on $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ corresponding to a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$.

Then, $\Phi_\sigma( a_1 ) + ... + \Phi_\sigma( a_k ) + \Phi_\sigma( b_1 ) + ... \Phi_\sigma( b_l ) = \Phi_\sigma(P)=P=a_1 + ... + a_k + b_1 + ... + b_l$.

This means that $\Phi_\sigma$ **permutes** the monomials of $P$ and this implies that $\Phi_\sigma$ fixes lacunary part.

Now note that $P(X_1,...,X_{n-1},0)$ is the sum of terms in the lacunary part which lack in $X_n$ and there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\{ \text{ terms of the lacunary part lacking in } X_i \}$ and $\{ \text{ terms of the lacunary part lacking in } X_n \}$. Hence by knowing if sums of terms lacking in $X_n$ of two different homogeneous polynomials are equal, then the whole lacunary parts of two are equal.